# Embed extracted images from gmail to custom client - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, gmail-api

I am using this gem to interact with the Gmail API: https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail

To fetch an email I have:

```
require 'gmail'
gmail = Gmail.connect("testemail@gmail.com", "password")

message = gmail.inbox.emails.last
puts message.message.html_part.body.raw_source
```

This returns the HTML format of the email, which is what I need, but the images show as missing when they are rendered, and the URL is in a weird format:

```
<div dir="ltr">see attached<div><br></div><div><img src="cid:ii_151afcf74cab7d3b" alt="Inline image 1" width="517" height="291"><br></div></div>
```

How do I get the full URL of the images so I can render them within the returned HTML?

I am aware of 3 possible approaches to this: https://www.codementor.io/tips/8112473532/strategies-for-serving-base64-encoded-images-in-html

I am trying to apply the first solution, how would I do this?

Comment: Could you show the entire response? :) I suspect the answer lies in the `headers`.

Comment: Do you mean like in the answer below? Does the article I posed help give a better idea of what i'm looking for?

Comment: A message contains a payload, with the `HTML`-part above, when it was created (`internalDate`), etc. It also contains a `headers` property which contains information about the `cids` and other things. I suspect it would be in `message.headers` or something similar where this information resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachments are hardcoded in the email body like so:

```
This is the body of the message.
--frontier
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+CiAgPGhlYWQ+CiAgPC9oZWFkPgogIDxib2R5PgogICAgPHA+VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUg
Ym9keSBvZiB0aGUgbWVzc2FnZS48L3A+CiAgPC9ib2R5Pgo8L2h0bWw+Cg==
--frontier--
```

You can decode attachments, store it as tempfiles a use it.

```
mail.attachments.each do | attachment |
  # Attachments is an AttachmentsList object containing a
  # number of Part objects
  if (attachment.content_type.start_with?('image/'))
    # extracting images for example...
    filename = attachment.filename
    begin
      File.open(images_dir + filename, "w+b", 0644) {|f| f.write attachment.body.decoded}
    rescue => e
      puts "Unable to save data for #{filename} because #{e.message}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn the hard coded part into a URL, so I do not have to save the file on my server?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just edited my question, please see the article I added. I am trying to embed the images within the HTML, using the URL hosted on Google's servers, instead of having to download the file and generate a new URL.

Comment: <img src="cid:ii_151afcf74cab7d3b" alt="Inline image 1" width="517" height="291"> its a link on an embed in the message body image. And you should decode an image content before using it. Read my answer.